# In need for usable JPA-Utilities

Tags: jpa, toplink-essentials

since my new project has to use toplink-essentials which only supports jpa 1, I'm looking for some good jpa-utilities. So far I only worked with jpa 2 (both EclipseLink and Hibernate), which didn't need any utilities to write dynamic queries in 99% of the time.

Now I'm stuck with jpa 1 and wondered if there were some utilities/libraries which could support me in writing my queries a little bit more dynamically.

Jonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TopLink Essentials does support Expression queries which are similar to JPA 2 Criteria.  You may be able to use them.

You should also be able to upgrade your server to EclipseLink.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about the Expression queries from Toplink. Makes life a little bit easier.  I know howto upgrade my server to EclipseLink, but I'm not allowed for nonsense reasons.